# Stop array from changing it's values

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got a mock-service configured Looking like this

```
import { Article } from "./article";

export const ARTICLES: Article[] = [
    new Article(
        1, 
        'used', 
        5060639120949, 
        'Monster Energy', 
        'NLZ0930EG', 
        'Espresso Monster Vanilla + Espresso',
        'Ein Espressomischgetränk mit Taurin, Milch und Vanilla-Flavour.',
        '../../assets/monster-espresso-vanilla.jpg',
        2.00,
        1,
        12,
        0.2,
        8,
        15,
        8
    ),
    new Article(
        2, 
        'used', 
        4018931180179, 
        'G Data', 
        'NLZ0930EG', 
        'G Data Inernet Secuirty Lizenzurkunde',
        'Lizenzurkunde der Vollversion von G Data Internet Security.',
        '../../assets/gdata-lizenzurkunde.jpg',
        40.00,
        1,
        12,
        0.2,
        8,
        15,
        0
    ),
    new Article(
        3, 
        'used', 
        4101090000638, 
        'Staatl. Fachingen', 
        'NLZ0930EG', 
        'Mineralwasser Medium',
        'Mineralwasser Medium feinperlend und erfrischend.',
        '../../assets/staatl.-fachingen-medium.jpg',
        0.89,
        1,
        57,
        1,
        10,
        25,
        10
    )
]
```

I Access this mock Array inside my data-service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Article } from '../model/article';
import { ARTICLES } from '../model/mock-data';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  private articles: Article[] = ARTICLES;
  articleCopy: Article[] = [...this.articles];

  fetchNeededArticle(eanCodeOfNeededArticle: number): Article {
    console.log(eanCodeOfNeededArticle);
    console.log(this.articleCopy);
    console.log(this.articleCopy.find(key => key.eanCode === eanCodeOfNeededArticle));
    const article: Article = this.articleCopy.find(article => article.eanCode === eanCodeOfNeededArticle);
    console.log('Ich wurde gefunden: ' + article);
    return article;
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

And I'm changing the initialQuantity value of a specific article by These method inside a different component

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Article } from 'src/app/model/article';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-article-preview',
  templateUrl: './article-preview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./article-preview.component.css']
})
export class ArticlePreviewComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() eanCodeOfNeededArticle: number;

  @Output() upcomingStep = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Output() fetchedArticle = new EventEmitter<Article>();

  articleForConfiguration: Article;

  changeStep(upcomingStep: string): void {
    this.upcomingStep.emit(upcomingStep);
  }

  initializeQuantity(operation: string): void {
    switch(operation){
      case 'substract':
        this.articleForConfiguration.initialQuantity = this.articleForConfiguration.initialQuantity - 1;
        console.log(this.articleForConfiguration.initialQuantity);
        break;
      case 'add':
        this.articleForConfiguration.initialQuantity = this.articleForConfiguration.initialQuantity + 1;
        break;
    }
  }

  fetchNeededArticle(eanCodeOfNeededArticle: number): void {
    const newArticle = this.dataService.fetchNeededArticle(eanCodeOfNeededArticle);
    this.articleForConfiguration = newArticle;
  }

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Wir brauchen dich: ' + this.eanCodeOfNeededArticle);
    if(this.eanCodeOfNeededArticle) {
      this.fetchNeededArticle(this.eanCodeOfNeededArticle);
    }
  }
}
```

(It's the initializeQuantity function)
But everytime I request the article again, the initialQuantity of These specific article is set to the value getting by the initializeQuantity() function. Sure after reloading the page the state is same and everything works well, but if I'm in the current application state, unfortunately the initialQuantitiy value changes change Deep even inside the mock-service data. I thought I carefully change the state by copying the mock Array several times by the spread Operator, but obviously this doesn't help.

Does anyone know where my Problem relates in?

Thank you very much in advice and have a great day!

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copied array might have a different reference, but the article objects inside each array is still the same. The copied array is not really necessary. At least not with your current requirements. What you need to do, is create a copy of the article itself:

```
export class DataService {
  private articles: Article[] = ARTICLES;

  fetchNeededArticle(ean: number): Article {
    const article = this.articles.find(article => article.eanCode === ean);

    return { ...article}; // here you create a shallow copy of the object
  }
}
```

Comment: This is called doing a 'deep copy'. Especially useful when working with nested objects.

Comment: @AlexBeugnet This is a shallow copy though. Any object inside `article` will still have the same reference. `const data = {}; const article = {data}; const copy = {...article}; data === copy.data // true`

Comment: Yes of course, I was just stating some additionnal information if the OP wants more information about the subject.

Comment: Thank you very much @PierreDuc that solved my Problem!